# COM Interop and thread synchronization

Tags: vb.net, com

I was doing some testing with COM Interop. I exported this test class:-

```
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ComSourceInterfaces(GetType(ICounterEvents))> _
Public Class Counter
Implements ICounter

Public Event CountTicked(ByVal current As Integer, ByVal max As Integer)

Public Sub StartCount(ByVal max As Integer) Implements ICounter.StartCount
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub() Count(max))
End Sub

Private Sub Count(ByVal max As Integer)

    For i = 1 To max
        Dim x As Integer = i

        'COM Seems to synchronize this automatically
        RaiseEvent CountTicked(x, max)

        Thread.Sleep(300)
    Next


End Sub


End Class
```

I tested the above in VB6 and it works as is which is quite strange. Notice that Count would be called on a worker thread so the event raised therein should be raised on the worker thread. Yet in VB6 I am able to change a Label's caption from the event handler with no problems or glitches which I would not expect. If this were done from VB.Net, it would throw a cross thread exception. My question is, what is going on when the class is used from VB6 ? Does COM automatically raise the event on the UI thread in the VB6 app ? Or does VB6 not care about controls being altered from worker threads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default VB6 creates all of it's objects in a single threaded apartment.  Whenever an object in VB6 is passed to another thread it actually passes a copy of the object (known as a proxy).

Calls to this proxy object from a background thread don't directly call into the original object on the UI thread.  Instead they are marshalled into calls on the UI thread through the message pump (using basically the same mechanism os `Control.Invoke` or `SynchronizationContext.Send`). This is why you can edit labels directly without having to hand marshal the call, the marshalling is done for you automatically

Here is an article which discusses this in a bit more depth

- [Apartment Model Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261361%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer Jared. So if I understand correctly, RaiseEvent actually calls CountTick on a proxy which then marshalls it back to the real object in its apartment ?

Comment: @Niya that would be the case in vb6