# Pass VB Function callback as parameter to .NET

Tags: .net, com, vb6, interop

Part of a Visual Basic program is being moved to .NET dll.

Parameter call can be passed successfully & everything run fine.

**How can I pass a callback function of VB6 for .NET to call after a long running async task?**

In .NET

```
Public Delegate Function VBCallBackFunc() As Integer

Public Function DoSomething(a As String, b As String, c As String, _
parent As IntPtr, Optional ByVal CallbackAddr As VBCallBackFunc = Nothing) As Boolean Implements _DotNetLib.DoSomething
```

VB6

```
result = DotNetLib.DoSomething(strA, strB, strC, Me.hwnd, AddressOf DotNetCallback)

Public Function DotNetCallback() As Long
    MsgBox ("Callback")
End Function
```

In object browser of VB:

```
Function DoSomething(strA As String, strB As String, strC As String,
 parent As Long, [CallbackAddr As VBCallBackFunc]) As Boolean

Member of DotNetLib
```

But it said "Invalid use of AddressOf operator" ???

Comment: Is `DotNetCallback` in a class module?

Comment: I tried moving to class module, now it's type mismatch error :/

Comment: It has to be in a normal module. The error you are quoting is when it's in a class module.

Comment: I did moved it to a normal module and that was the result ;/  Did I do something wrong in the .NET part? I added the function description in VB Object Browser FYI

Comment: VB6 does not have typed callbacks, they should be `Long`. What is `VBCallBackFunc` as far as VB6 sees it?

Comment: Weird. VB can only see VBCallBackFunc as a Class, Member of DotNetLib. Should I define something other than Delegate for VB to pass?

Comment: Declare it as `IntPtr` on VB.NET side.

Comment: You should use .NET COM events instead. It's much safer than raw callbacks : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd8bf0x3(v=vs.100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments related to using Events are a good option, but I tend to use interfaces more, so here is a solution for that.

(Free-hand code, you will need to syntax check and the names can be cleaned up, they are just for illustration purposes)

In .NET:

Create an COM exposed interface for your callback:

```
Public Interface IVBCallBack
   Public Function VBCallBackFunc() As Integer
End Interface
```

Change your DoSomething be like this:

```
Public Function DoSomething(a As String, b As String, c As String, parent As IntPtr, ByVal CallbackAddr As IVBCallBack) As Boolean
```

In VB6:

```
result = DotNetLib.DoSomething(strA, strB, strC, Me.hwnd, Me)
```

(And you will need your class, control, or form to `Implements IVBCallBack`)

```
Public Function IVBCallBack_VBCallBackFunc() As Long
    MsgBox ("Callback")
End Function
```

Be sure to have a method on the .NET side to clean up and release all your references since .NET is holding a reference to the VB6 object.

One other thing to note.  DO NOT CALL BACK INTO VB6 ON ANY THREAD OTHER THAN THE MAIN UI THREAD!

Comment: Plus one - AFAICR using events in COM/.Net interop is a bit flaky so I would choose this option

Comment: Question was for "For .NET to call after a long running async task". Events should shield the developer from threading or dangling cross referencing issues (provided VB code pumps windows messages)

Comment: Events can be called on other threads, but for sure, as I opened with, Events are a good option.  I have hit some issues with them in the past that I don't recall the specifics of (VB6 is getting old now) so I ended up going with an Interface approach and never looked back.

Comment: Interestingly, I found this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224220/com-interop-and-thread-synchronization) that indicates that perhaps my warning was premature and that the magic of COM interop will take care of the threading.  YMMV

Comment: This works well. After VB6 Implements DotNetLib.IVBCallBack, function is now called successfully from .NET in main thread using Invoke. Nicely done, many thanks!